# Images sharp after visiting product page

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

When visiting product page, and then go back, the thumnails that is visited is sharp. I tried gaining thumnail size in woocommerce setting and tried scaling with trough css but have really now idea what it can be.

If you look to the first image you see its a bit more blurry then second image:

[image]

So here on the second image you see its more sharper

[image]

It is really strange, please advise how I can solf this problem. link: https://luzachorloges.nl/

I think maybe its something wrong configured but maybe can someone take a look at css.

Comment: I tried the same way as you said, opened your website and visited a product and then come back to home page again. For me, both thumbnails were same, nothing changed. 

Actually thumbnails are having original image path as well, maybe according to the screen resolution your HTML page is loading full image after visiting the product page.

At this moment you are using 300x300 for thumbnails.

Comment: I have gone through your website and found the there are two pints which is suspect.

1 is transition effect which is not work perfectly I have disable the effect and after that image is clear.

2nd point is you have used the lazy load option in your site which is conflict may be.

Here I have shared the screen-shot for your reference.

Screen-shot: https://prnt.sc/12aesh4

Comment: thanks @ZealousWeb for the replly, when change CSS in inspecttor to "transition: none!important" it stil zooms in when hover. Do you have any suggestion to disable zoom and any kind of animation. thanks for your time and reply sir :)